# Template class name with <> mark

Tags: c++, templates

```
  template<int32_t ID= 0, class ID_TYPE = int32_t>
  class Event {
  public:
      typedef ID_TYPE type;
      typedef Event<ID, ID_TYPE> event_obj_type;
   .....  
}
```

About this code, what does  "`Event<ID, ID_TYPE>`" mean?
class name with <>, i never seen this before.
Could anybody enlighten me?
thanks

Comment: You have tagged this question with `templates`, so apparently you know that this is a class template. `Event` simply is its name, similar to `class Banana`. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event is a template : a pattern for creating similar classes at compile time.
If at some places of your code you make :
    Event<0, int32_t> A;
    Event<3, char> A;

Two classes will be defined from this template. One with `ID = 0, ID_TYPE = int32_t` and the other with `ID = 3, ID_TYPE = char`.

[EDIT]
If you decompose the first one, your class definition will be something like :

```
class Event
{
    public:
    typedef int32_t type;
    typedef Event event_obj_type;
    .....  
}
```

Comment: But the question is about the typedef, surely?

Comment: so,   classname with <> ,, what is this , terminology wise? thanks!

Comment: <> is used to precise the types used for the instance of the templated class. It is a c++ core syntax. See basics of templates in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably familiar with function templates. This:

```
Event<ID, ID_TYPE>
```

is a **class template**. Unlike function template instantiation, where arguments of function itself helps the compiler to deduce template type arguments, with class templates you must explicitly pass template type (in angle brackets).

[An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1#ClassTempl)